# NextJS and persist layout that contains Leaflet

Tags: reactjs, next.js, leaflet, react-leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I'm migrating a project from `React` to `NextJS` which has a layout where the common component is a `Leaflet Map`.

1. In Next JS, the "next/dynamic" used to load the map
2. React used react-router-dom@v6
3. [next layout](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts)

Layout code:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import React, { useMemo, useState } from "react";

const DynamicLeafletMap = dynamic(
  () => import("../components/LeafletMap/LeafletMap"),
  {
    ssr: false,
  }
);

function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <main>
      <DynamicLeafletMap />
      {children}
    </main>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

_app.js code:

```
import Layout from "../components/Layout";

import "../styles/globals.scss";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

LeafletMap.jsx

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import styles from "./LeafletMap.module.scss";

const initial_position = [38.9637, 35.2433];

function LeafletMap() {
  return (
    <>
        <div className={styles.map}>
          <MapContainer
            center={initial_position}
            zoom={4}
            scrollWheelZoom={true}
            className={styles.map__container}
          >
            <TileLayer
              attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
              url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
          </MapContainer>
        </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default LeafletMap;
```

The problem is that when using "`router.push`" (for example, clicking on a marker should open a modal window on top of the map), the map is **rerendered** and **reseted**.
I tried different ways like useMemo, createPortal but this didn't work.
Is there a way to fix this behaviour? Maybe there is another framework that provides functionality like "**persist layout**"?

Comment: I cant see that you have any props going down to the map component. Do you have all the logic in the LeafletMap component?

Comment: Disco, yes. The map is rendered even without a marker tile. I have added the code.

Comment: That the page rerenders on navigation feels like the correct behaviour. Could you share the code where you use `router.push`. Did some tests in my project where I just add to query and the map do not rerender.
```push({
              pathname: pathname,
              query: { ...query, lat: position[0] },
            });```

Comment: I am not using query parameters.
Flow navigation example: 
1. Initially on "/" - map is rendered
2. router.push("/{lang}/collection/{slug|id}") opens SSR modal on top of the map, which is rerendered.

I found the correct behavior in Remix which uses spa like nesting. But still want to find a way to use NextJS (I saw that the new Layouts RFC hasn't been implemented yet and was looking for a workaround ).

Answer (score -1):

> Next13 with new app directory or Remix solves this problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).